# Running a program with the same as an existing command

Tags: linux, tcsh

Let's say I make a runnable program called "xeyes.exe" in my current directory.

When I type the command "xeyes" into the command prompt, why does the program run instead of the command?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Is it WSL? Is it bash? Cause on a linux box, in order to run anything from your current dir, you need to write `./` before it: `./something`.... unless `PATH` has `./` as one of its members? which I don't think is good practice. What is the output of `echo $PATH`? Add that as info in the original question, if you don't mind

Comment: @eftshift0 You're right! PATH has `.` as one of its members. 
I didn't see it before, thanks!

Comment: aside from the PATH issue, `xeyes.exe` is **not** the same filename as `xeyes`.

Answer (score 1):

> why does the program run instead of the command?

Because Unix is a secure multi-user system.

It does not make assumptions about files based on their names - their behaviour is defined in meta-data.

By default, the shell will only run programs from defined locations unless you explicitly tell it do otherwise.

Suppose I created a program which deleted random files sent rude emails and emailed me a copy of the running user's private ssh keys and named it 'ls' and left it in a directory used by lots of people?